# Make order number group by fields

Tags: mysql

I have this data stored in MySQL:

```
|  name  |  number  |  group  |
-------------------------------
| godard |          |    1    |
| gaylord|          |    1    |
| linda  |          |    1    |
| demi   |          |    2    |
| micha  |          |    2    |
```

I want to insert order number but by group field. So the table look like this:

```
|  name  |  number   |  group  |
-------------------------------
| godard |     1     |    1    |
| gaylord|     2     |    1    |
| linda  |     3     |    1    |
| demi   |     1     |    2    |
| micha  |     2     |    2    |
```

Can I do this in MySQL:

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using below query.

```
SET @a = 1; 
SET @past = '';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_test` (
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `group` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `number` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
SELECT t.name as name, if(@past = t.`group`, @a:= @a + 1, @a:= 1) as             
number, @past:= t.`group` as 'group'
FROM test t
ORDER BY t.`group`;

UPDATE test
INNER JOIN temp_test ON test.name = temp_test.name AND test.`group` =     temp_test.`group` SET test.number = temp_test.number WHERE test.number IS NULL OR test.number = 0 OR test.number = '';

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_test;
```

Comment: but its not inserted on the table??

Comment: Do you wish to update or wish to insert into completely new table.

Comment: Do you primary key in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

The @row_num variable holds the current row number and the @pev_value variable holds the current value of the partition by field.

```
UPDATE TEMP T join 

(select o.Name,@row_num := IF(@prev_value=o.group,@row_num+1,1) AS Number
      ,@prev_value := o.group AS `Group`
      from temp o ,
      (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
      (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
 )a on a.name=T.name and a.`group` =T.`group` 
SET T.number = a.Number\\

select * from temp
```

[Demo Link](http://rextester.com/KQDQ46135)

> OutPut :

[image]

let us know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: can i update the final select into the current table?

Comment: Yes. You Can. Code and Demo Link Updated. Check It.

Comment: @www.cahyonegoro.com you checked or not .? is it working ?